# Column already exists in LeftJoin with Zend

Tags: zend-framework

With relationship and joins I'm trying get the latest post of each customer.
But I don't really get it to work. I get error:
Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 'custID'

Based on my searching both here and Google it could have been for * but I have removed so all table columns is specified by name so I don't get why I get column already exists?

```
    $db = $this->getDbTable();

// create sub query
$subSql = $db->select()
                ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
                ->from(array('s1' => 'sales'), array('s1.custID', 's1.saledate'))
                ->joinLeft(array('s2' => 'sales'), 's1.custID = s2.custID AND s1.saledate < s2.saledate', array('s2.custID', 's2.saledate'))
                ->where('s2.custID IS NULL')
                ->limit(1);

//main query
    $sql = $db->select()
                     ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
                     ->from(array('customers' => 'customers'), array("customers.custID"))
                     ->joinLeft(array('sale_tmp' => new Zend_Db_Expr('(' . $subSql . ')')), "customers.custID = sale_tmp.custID", array('sale_tmp.custID'));




//echo $sql->assemble();    
//exit; 

$resultSet = $db->fetchAll($sql);
return $resultSet;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since two of your tables have the field `custID`, there is a conflict about how to populate the `custID` value in your joined table.

You need to provide a column-alias for one of them. The signature of the `joinLeft()` method is:

`joinLeft($table, $condition, [$columns])`

The third argument `$columns` can be a straight integer-indexed array of columns (as you are using) or it can be an associative array whose values are the columns, but whose keys are the *column-aliases*.

So perhaps try something like:

```
// create sub query
// add alias for the custID field
$subSql = $db->select()
    ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
    ->from(array('s1' => 'sales'), array('s1.custID', 's1.saledate'))
    ->joinLeft(array('s2' => 'sales'), 's1.custID = s2.custID AND s1.saledate < s2.saledate', array('sales_custID' => 's2.custID', 's2.saledate'))
    ->where('s2.custID IS NULL')
    ->limit(1);

// main query
// add alias for custID field
$sql = $db->select()
     ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
     ->from(array('customers' => 'customers'), array("customers.custID"))
     ->joinLeft(array('sale_tmp' => new Zend_Db_Expr('(' . $subSql . ')')), "customers.custID = sale_tmp.custID", array('temp_custID' => sale_tmp.custID'));
```